# how to specify hourly time range in djagno?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to accept orders within specific timeframe, simply i want to validated orders if they are within 8:00-19:00 no matter what day it is or what date it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows using datetime:

```
def your_function(request):
    current_time = dt.now(tz=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('UTC'))
    if 8 < current_time.hour < 19:
        # Accept the order and process accordingly
    else:
        # Don't accept and send different response
```